# Renaming/translating "your profile" page

Tags: profiles, translation

I need to rename/translate the "Your Profile" page. I've used the function below

```
function pietergoosen_hoofskerm_vertaling( $translated ) {
 $words = array(
                    'Name' => 'Naam',

                );
 $translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($words),  $words,  $translated );
 return $translated;
}
add_filter(  'gettext',  'pietergoosen_hoofskerm_vertaling'  );
```

The problem is, this change all instances of Name to Naam, even when name is part of word or sentence, like 'UserName' get changed to 'UserNaam' and 'Display Name publicly as' get changed to 'Display Naam publicly as'.

Any other ways to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of PHP implementation detail. If you want a precise match you can do something like:

```
if ( isset( $words[$translated] ) )
    return $words[$translated];

return $translated;
```

PS you might want to declare `$words` as static, so that array is reused and not continuously re-created on each function call (which would be *a lot* of calls with `gettext` hook).

Comment: Sorry Rarst, can you please give me an example of how to implement it. Not quite sure how to do it. Many thanks

Comment: @PieterGoosen answer has code for you to try in your filter function?.. I don't see how more example-ish I can make it.

Comment: never tried it but maybe you can limit impact with some conditional statement : `if( 'profile.php' == $hook_suffix )` and pass `$hook_suffix` as an argument of your function.